# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: port, firewall

I have one server called 'testapp'  and client machine called 'clientapp'.I am trying to install one windowservice called 'SVM' on client machine. If install 'SVM' in 'clientapp' and configure 'testapp' as Server here in this service tab,  Then in server 'testapp' i can see client machine as connected and server will start monitoring.

But what actually going is i am not able to install windowservice on client. I am getting error which is mentioned down as trace file:

Comment: Every ip address starting with 127. will end up on your local machine! You should use another range. 127. is for local host only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.xx.xx.xx is reserved for [loopback](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPReservedPrivateandLoopbackAddresses.htm) to the same machine - in other words, that's not *actually* trying to talk to the server. It's unclear where that address has come from, but if you find the right address, it may just start to work.

Comment: i didnt get you john, u mean 127.27.10.10? this shud be in etc\serivces or host file

Comment: @Simon - wherever you set the IP `127.27.10.10` you should actually be putting the IP of the server `testapp` and this won't be the `127.x.x.x` address...

Comment: Does that belongs to the issues with port 7003. Our product is defined in this way that SVM service is managing port 7003 , do i need to add ports in serivce file

Comment: okey i will post host file of server in my question can you verify it

Comment: John i have posted my host file

Answer (score 1):

Actively refused it means that the machine was reachable but it replied with a nack.
This means that nothing is listening on that port for that IP address.

You have to assure that your server is listening and that he is listening for connections on your localhost.

It could probably help too if you just used 127.0.0.1 as local host. Whatever you put after 127. will connect you with your local host, but 127.0.0.1 is used by convention.